# Prestashop : Showing back-office custom tab content in product.tpl in front-office

Tags: hook, prestashop

I went through the following tutorial : http://nemops.com/prestashop-products-new-tabs-fields/ and I found myself unable to add the content of the fields into my front-office product.tpl page. 
I assume I have all the tools to get the result I want, but I am getting lost in this code and I am not comfortable with hooks yet. Could someone please give a moment to help me, and tell me how to display a custom .tpl file containing my data at a specific hook/location in the front-office page? I've spent time browsing several tutorials and documentations but I still struggle.

I would really appreciate help, regards.